# How to encrypt video from url and save encrypted video to device's SD Card

Tags: java, android, video, encryption

In my application I have to use of many video files. Approximately total size of all the video is 500 MB. So I have to decide at the first time when application is install and run at that tike I download videos in background and after encrypting that video saved it to device's SD Card. When ever video is used I decrypt that video and use it.

I decide this because all the video files are very important, so Security of that file is very important..

I try very much to find how to encrypt video & save it to SD Card...

Finally one thing I found that I put below but In this code error occurred PERMISSION DENIED.

**Code:**

```
public class VideoActivity extends Activity 
{
    VideoView video_view;
    MediaController m_controller;
    MediaPlayer mplayer;
    String[] a = {"1","2","3","4","5","6"};

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


        try {
            main(a);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

        public void writeToFile(String filename, Object object) throws Exception 
        {
            FileOutputStream fos = null;
            ObjectOutputStream oos = null;

            try 
            {
                fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/corebird1.mp4"));
                oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
                oos.writeObject(object);
                oos.flush();
            }
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally 
            {
                if (oos != null) 
                {
                    oos.close();
                }
                if (fos != null) 
                {
                    fos.close();
                }
            }
        }

        public void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
        {
            //
            // Generating a temporary key and stire it in a file.
            //
            SecretKey key = KeyGenerator.getInstance("DES").generateKey();
            writeToFile("secretkey.dat", key);
            Log.d("#######key", String.valueOf(key));

            //
            // Preparing Cipher object for encryption.
            //
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);

            //
            // Here we seal (encrypt) a simple string message (a string object).
            //
            SealedObject sealedObject = new SealedObject("THIS IS A SECRET MESSAGE!", cipher);

            //
            // Write the object out as a binary file.
            //
            writeToFile("sealed.dat", sealedObject);
        } 
}
```

**LogCat:**

```
08-10 12:22:32.430: WARN/System.err(338): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard/corebird1.mp4 (Permission denied)
08-10 12:22:32.430: WARN/System.err(338):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSFileSystem.openImpl(Native Method)
08-10 12:22:32.459: WARN/System.err(338):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSFileSystem.open(OSFileSystem.java:152)
08-10 12:22:32.459: WARN/System.err(338):     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:97)
08-10 12:22:32.459: WARN/System.err(338):     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:69)
08-10 12:22:32.459: WARN/System.err(338):     at com.technosoft.video.VideoActivity.writeToFile(VideoActivity.java:71)
08-10 12:22:32.459: WARN/System.err(338):     at com.technosoft.video.VideoActivity.main(VideoActivity.java:99)
08-10 12:22:32.459: WARN/System.err(338):     at com.technosoft.video.VideoActivity.onCreate(VideoActivity.java:54)
08-10 12:22:32.459: WARN/System.err(338):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
08-10 12:22:32.459: WARN/System.err(338):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
08-10 12:22:32.459: WARN/System.err(338):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
08-10 12:22:32.470: WARN/System.err(338):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
08-10 12:22:32.470: WARN/System.err(338):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
08-10 12:22:32.470: WARN/System.err(338):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-10 12:22:32.470: WARN/System.err(338):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-10 12:22:32.470: WARN/System.err(338):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
08-10 12:22:32.470: WARN/System.err(338):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-10 12:22:32.470: WARN/System.err(338):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-10 12:22:32.480: WARN/System.err(338):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
08-10 12:22:32.480: WARN/System.err(338):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
08-10 12:22:32.480: WARN/System.err(338):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-10 12:22:32.480: DEBUG/#######key(338): javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec@69
08-10 12:22:32.510: WARN/System.err(338): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard/corebird1.mp4 (Permission denied)
08-10 12:22:32.510: WARN/System.err(338):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSFileSystem.openImpl(Native Method)
08-10 12:22:32.520: WARN/System.err(338):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSFileSystem.open(OSFileSystem.java:152)
08-10 12:22:32.520: WARN/System.err(338):     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:97)
08-10 12:22:32.520: WARN/System.err(338):     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:69)
08-10 12:22:32.520: WARN/System.err(338):     at com.technosoft.video.VideoActivity.writeToFile(VideoActivity.java:71)
08-10 12:22:32.520: WARN/System.err(338):     at com.technosoft.video.VideoActivity.main(VideoActivity.java:116)
08-10 12:22:32.520: WARN/System.err(338):     at com.technosoft.video.VideoActivity.onCreate(VideoActivity.java:54)
08-10 12:22:32.520: WARN/System.err(338):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
08-10 12:22:32.520: WARN/System.err(338):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
08-10 12:22:32.520: WARN/System.err(338):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
08-10 12:22:32.520: WARN/System.err(338):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
08-10 12:22:32.520: WARN/System.err(338):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
08-10 12:22:32.520: WARN/System.err(338):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-10 12:22:32.520: WARN/System.err(338):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-10 12:22:32.520: WARN/System.err(338):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
08-10 12:22:32.520: WARN/System.err(338):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-10 12:22:32.520: WARN/System.err(338):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-10 12:22:32.530: WARN/System.err(338):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
08-10 12:22:32.530: WARN/System.err(338):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
08-10 12:22:32.530: WARN/System.err(338):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Any body have solution for this error, then please help me...

or If u have any other solution or suggestions then also u can help...I am thankful for that....

I want also method for decrypt the encode video and play that android.

Any body have any other

Answer (score 1):

The error you are seeing has nothing to do with encryption and everything to do with file permissions. Does your app request permission to use the SD card?

Secondly, why DES? DES is usually substantially slower than AES on modern hardware, and has keys that are far too short for modern use. Also, make sure you are using a GCM, CTR or CBC mode of operation - simple ECB does not have good security properties.

Do realize that you are implementing a classic DRM scheme: anyone with access to the device and the application private directory will be able to locate the secret key file and decrypt the video, or steal the video in transit.

Comment: Yes, I add permission for sd card uses in AndroidManifest file.

Comment: I have no Idea about encryption & decryption...can please suggest me with methods suits better for my problem??

Comment: @Mohit - if you want info on encryption look at crypto.stackexchange.com or security.stackexchange.com